# Ionic build error: Unable to open file for read: Permission denied for Android manifest xml file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build

I am new in ionic platform. I am running ionic v1 project in my Windows 10 OS. After executing "ionic build android" in my node js command prompt for my project directory path, I get the following error:

```
:CordovaLib:processDebugResourcesC:\Users\vm48407\Desktop\ZenTS_V3.0.5\ZenTs_Ionic_v3.0.5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: Unable to open file for read: Permission denied FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.041 secs
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\vm48407\Desktop\ZenTS_V3.0.5\ZenTs_Ionic_v3.0.5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: Unable to open file for read: Permission denied


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I checked the properties of the project folder and all permissions regarding read/write are already there, and I still get the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582401/2033377