# Unable to open file for read: Permission denied

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-manifest, permission-denied, aapt

Suddenly for my IONIC project I started to getting below mentioned error

[image]

I have android sdk setup as mentioned below :
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Android SDK Platform-tools : 26
Android SDK Build-tools : 26

Would you please help me for the same.

I have tried with :
1) Delete android project from platform and created new one
2) Given all the permission to platforms folder and to its subfolders

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

There was an issue with new android-sdk > build-tools > 25.0.2.

So I have deleted build-tools from Android SDK folders which has version more than 25.0.2.

Now build and run the project and that works for me.